# Making an SQL statement which dynamically chooses INNER JOIN based on content of one column in results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
$sql =  "
    SELECT
        id,
        refid,
        action_id,
        action_type,
        co_user_id,
        cust_vend_id,
        cust_vend_type,
        Aes_decrypt(cust_vend_name, '".DBKEY."') AS cust_vend_name,
        Aes_decrypt(amount, '".DBKEY."')         AS amount,
        Aes_decrypt(action_date, '".DBKEY."')   AS action_date,
        Aes_decrypt(memo, '".DBKEY."')         AS memo,
        Aes_decrypt(trans_id, '".DBKEY."')     AS trans_id,
        entry_datetime,
        part_id,
        polarity
    FROM
        generated_actions
    WHERE  acc_type = 1
        AND acc_id = $ref_id
        AND action_type != 2
        AND reverse_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY generated_actions.action_id DESC ";
```

It works, but I need to add an INNER JOIN ON either `customers` or `vendors` depending on whether the contents of `cust_vend_type` column is a '1' (customers) or '2' (vendors) and then grab `customers_comp_name` if '1' or `vendors_comp_name' if '2'.

Looking forward to choosing the best solution or marking up helpful advice!

**UPDATE**

This is the code updated with @ciaran's response below. The problem is that it seems to be returning an empty resultset even though I know there are qualified records.

```
$sql =  "
    SELECT
        ga.id,
        ga.refid,
        ga.action_id,
        ga.action_type,
        ga.co_user_id,
        ga.cust_vend_id,
        ga.cust_vend_type,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.amount, '".DBKEY."')                 AS amount,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.action_date, '".DBKEY."')            AS action_date,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.memo, '".DBKEY."')                   AS memo,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.trans_id, '".DBKEY."')               AS trans_id,
        ga.entry_datetime,
        ga.part_id,
        ga.polarity,
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN
            ga.cust_vend_type IS NULL
        THEN
            NULL
        WHEN
            ga.cust_vend_type = '1'
        THEN
            AES_DECRYPT(c.cust_comp_name, '".DBKEY."')
        ELSE
            AES_DECRYPT(v.vendor_comp_name, '".DBKEY."') END AS cust_vend_name
        FROM
            generated_actions ga
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            customers c
        ON
            c.cust_id = ga.cust_vend_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            vendors v
        ON
            v.vendor_id = ga.cust_vend_id
        WHERE
            ga.acc_type = 1
        AND
            ga.acc_id = $ref_id
        AND
            ga.action_type != 2
        AND
            ga.reverse_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY
            ga.action_id DESC ";
```

Not sure what I've done wrong?

Comment: Is there only one customer id on generated_actions? or is there a vendor_id **AND** a customer_id. If both are they both always valid ids, i.e no nulls. I suspect there's only one customer_id?

Comment: the cust_vend_id is represents either the vendor_id of the vendors table or the cust_id of the customers table, depending on whether cust_vend_type is 1 or 2.

Comment: don't use mysql_*, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: thanks rOcKiNg I have converted recently most of the site to use PDO. This is a legacy query which will be converted shortly too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outer join and then use an CASE (or IF) to select the correct name...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN generated_actions.cust_vend_type Is Null Then Null 
            WHEN generated_actions.cust_vend_type = '1'
            THEN customers.customers_comp_name
            ELSE vendors.vendors_comp_name END as Cust_Vend_Name

  FROM generated_actions

       LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.id=generated_actions.cust_vend_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN vendors ON vendors.id=generated_actions.cust_vend_id
```

i.e. your query should read...

```
$sql =  "
    SELECT
        ga.id,
        ga.refid,
        ga.action_id,
        ga.action_type,
        ga.co_user_id,
        ga.cust_vend_id,
        ga.cust_vend_type,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.amount, '".DBKEY."')                 AS amount,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.action_date, '".DBKEY."')            AS action_date,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.memo, '".DBKEY."')                   AS memo,
        Aes_decrypt(ga.trans_id, '".DBKEY."')               AS trans_id,
        ga.entry_datetime,
        ga.part_id,
        ga.polarity,
        CASE WHEN ga.cust_vend_type IS NULL THEN NULL
             WHEN ga.cust_vend_type = '1' THEN AES_DECRYPT(c.cust_comp_name, '".DBKEY."')
             ELSE AES_DECRYPT(v.vendor_comp_name, '".DBKEY."') END AS cust_vend_name
   FROM generated_actions ga
        LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c ON c.cust_id = ga.cust_vend_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vendors v ON ga.cust_vend_id
  WHERE ga.acc_type = 1
    AND ga.acc_id = $ref_id
    AND ga.action_type != 2
    AND ga.reverse_id IS NULL
  ORDER BY ga.action_id DESC ";
```

Comment: Sorry, Ciaran, your solution came just after I got the chosen answer to work. Yours looks like another good solution tackling it from another angle, so +1

Comment: I've updated my question to show the updated code using your solution. It's returning an empty result set currently, which is not right. Just wondering if you can check my implementation of your solution to ensure I've understood it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: You've copied the SELECT keyword in as well. Remove it and it'll work. I amended my answer to show this.

Comment: @PeterSnow Plz, decrease your code to the minimal example, that is giving an error. And tell us the database content and inputs, that you use. What data are you trying to retrieve? It is very hard to dig into someone else's big code, trying to comprehend, how it must work.

Comment: Thanks guys. I couldn't see a difference except for formatting between my updated code and yours but dropped yours in to be sure and after correcting small issue on line 22 of yours, it now's, your version works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Whoops, I've fixed that typo. Thanks for pointing it out Peter. Your code had a `SELECT` in it just before the `CASE` Statement.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to inner join both of the tables. And use an IF statement:

```
SELECT
    IF(generated_actions.cust_vend_type = 1, customers.customers_comp_name, vendors.vendors_comp_name)
FROM
    generated_actions
INNER JOIN
    customers
ON
    customers.id=generated_actions.customer_id
INNER JOIN
    vendors
ON
    vendors.id=generated_actions.vendor_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Will have a play with it and report back.

Comment: generated_actions.customer_id doesn't seem to exist and even if you replace it with cust_vend_id this SQL will return nothing unless entries exist in both customers and vendors for the cust_vend_id.

Comment: Seems to be working @Ciaran but will test it further (needed to slightly correct the column names.

Comment: Sorry user4035 & @Ciaran, have had deselect the answer as not quite there yet! The problem I've discovered is that apart from cust_vend_type being 1 or 2, it can also be NULL! When it's null, the 'AS cust_vend_name' needs to still be returned even though empty, as it is echoed later by PHP (although empty). Thanks and sorry to mess you around.

Comment: Well then you definitely do need an outer join, but with an expanded CASE statement and I've amended my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @PeterSnow if NULL may occur, then CASE Statement, provided by Ciarán, will work perfectly.